# Affine connection on a manifold induced by acceleration field

Tags: forces, differential-geometry, acceleration, geodesics

Suppose I have a classical force field that accelerates all particles, such that the acceleration is a function $A(p, v)$ of position and 4-velocity alone. E.g., Newtonian gravity with a possible "magnetic" term. I then consider a vector quantity $w^\gamma$ (e.g., the displacement of a meterstick) moving at velocity $v^\beta$. Is it possible to calculate the acceleration experienced by $w^\gamma$, i.e., its rate of change per unit (proper) time?

In terms of manifolds, I believe this rephrases as follows. Consider Minkowski space as the manifold $\mathbb{R}^4$, equipped with geodesics defined by the paths that particles follow. Specifically, assume there is some ${A^\alpha}_{\beta \gamma}(p)$ such that the geodesics are
$$\frac{dv^\alpha}{ds} + {A^\alpha}_{\beta \gamma}v^\beta v^\gamma = 0$$
for proper time $s$. Then I seek the affine connection coefficients ${\Gamma^\alpha}_{\beta \gamma}$.

**Thoughts so far**

I know that in general, a manifold's geodesics do not determine ${\Gamma^\alpha}_{\beta \gamma}$; at most we know $${\Gamma^\alpha}_{(\beta \gamma)} = {A^\alpha}_{(\beta \gamma)},$$ while the torsion $2{\Gamma^\alpha}_{[\beta \gamma]}$ is unconstrained. But in this case, we have the extra assumption that we started in Minkowski space, where straight lines are inertial frames. This rules out e.g. a twisted coordinate system in which "straight lines" are actually helixes with nonzero torsion.

Put another way: since the meterstick is made out of particles, it seems like we should know how it accelerates. However, I cannot find a formula that is bilinear in $v$ and $w$.

Answer (score 0):

Find a metric written in the form [(20), page 6](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Efratus/phys103/LN/IGR.pdf) (Rindler coordinates) for example and replace the $g_{ij}$ in [Christoffel symbols of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols).

Comment: The Christoffel symbols of the second kind always have 0 torsion, but it's not clear to me that there should be 0 torsion in this case. Indeed, the acceleration field could have magnetism-like eddies that induce a torque.

Comment: Already in the definition of the cristoffel symbols of 1st and 2nd species, there is a condition of symmetry with respect to the index $(i,j)$, $\Gamma_{ij}^{k}=\Gamma_{ji}^{ k}$ , i.e. the torsion tensor $S_{ij}^{k}=\Gamma_{ij}^{k}-\Gamma_{jk}^{k}$ is zero,
this guarantees the possibility to define a translation along any geodsic line.